# Areca ARC 1261ML only sees 2TB on 4TB Disks

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, seagate

I recently acquired a Supermicro Box with a Areca ARC 1261 ML. I have installed 16 X Seagate ST4000VN000-1H4168 (4TB Drives). The ARC 1261ML controller only sees 2TB of usable space on the 4TB drive. When attempting to build a new RAID array, I enable 64-bit LBA for greater than 2TB support, and still only 2TB of each disk are usable.

What might cause this?

Controller Card Information: 
[image: Controller Card Information]

Disk Information: 
[image: Disk Information]

Comment: You have 1.46 firmware. Try updating to the [latest (1.49) firmware](ftp://ftp.areca.com.tw/RaidCards/BIOS_Firmware/OldProducts/ARC1260/).

Comment: Attempting to update from 1.46 to 1.49 yields "invalid firmware signature" despite having tried through Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11 (after reading that certain browsers might cause this issue) any other ideas? I was thinking of attempting to re-apply the 1.46 firmware to ensure that all components (FIRM, BOOT, MBR0, and BIOS) were fully updated before reattempting the 1.49 update. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the firmware from 1.46 to 1.49 resolved this issue.